# Webpage crashes when loading obj file using Babylon.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, babylonjs

I purchased a 3d scene in the file format of obj, as well as some texture files. The obj file has 187 MB. I tried using the following code to load the obj file (I tested my code with other obj sample files, works ok). However, after a while of loading, my webpage crashes afterwards. I uploaded the screenshot of the webpage after it crashes.

I use babylon.2.4.js, babylon.objFileLoader.js, node.js for my web service and IIS for the server.

I was wondering can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you so much!!!

Yours Sincerely,

Chi Xiao

```
    var camera;

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');
        var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);

        engine.enableOfflineSupport = false;

        BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("http://127.0.0.1:8082/scenes/kc8/", "kc8.obj", engine, function (newScene)
        { 
            camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", 3 * Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 8, 50, BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), newScene);
            camera.attachControl(canvas, true);

            var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("hemi", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), newScene);
            light.diffuse = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
            light.specular = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
            light.groundColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);

            engine.runRenderLoop(function() 
            {
                newScene.render();
            });

            window.addEventListener('resize', function() 
            {
                engine.resize();
            });
        });
    });
```

[image: Screenshot of the webpage on Chrome]

[image: Screenshot of the console on Chrome]

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: @DavidBasalla No, I don't see any error messages, as you can see in the screenshot picture. However, I think I know what is going on now. My obj file contains vertices larger than the maximum number of vertices provided by WebGL. I need to figure out how to reduce the number of vertices in the scene.